# ERROR:ml is not a member of package org.apache.flink using ZEPPELIN

Tags: apache-flink, apache-zeppelin, flink-streaming

I am starting to develop a machine algorithm in Zeppelin.
As interpreter I am using Flink.

- **Problem:**

  Flink machine learning library is not included in Zeppelin.
- **Error:**

  import org.apache.flink.ml.common.LabeledVector
  import org.apache.flink.ml.math.DenseVector
  :75: error: object ml is not a member of package org.apache.flink
         import org.apache.flink.ml.common.LabeledVector
- **Solution:**

  Below, in the answer of *1ambda*.

  (Also you can download the dependencies .jar from here:
    [maven.org](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cflink%20ml) with the version what you want, and add into the artifact the route of the file in your sistem)

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flink-ml_2.10` is not included in Zeppelin.

But, you can load external dependencies like this

- go to `localhosdt:8080/#/interpreter`
- find the `flink` interpreter
- add `org.apache.flink:flink-ml_2.10:1.1.3` as a new dependency
- then, save it. (will restart flink interpreter)

[image]

Comment: **Thanks for your answer** I knew it was something about some library/dependence/.jar but I wouldn't be able to think this ever hahaha. Just one thing, in your third point ("Add org...") I think you wrote a 'h' in the middle of orhg.apache....